# Extracting number from in pandas dataframe column with 2 conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have this dataframe with 1 column in python and i need to extract out the 2 numbers that come after a **"#"** character or the string **"door"**. Example of this would be

```
String_column
#12-123,456
mom101, door 101, pop10
```

i only want the 2 numbers that come after the # sign or the word door. how would i go about doing this.
This is what i currently have but i think this only takes in the numbers that come after the # key

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(data.csv)
df['qwerty'] = df.string_column.str.extract(
     r'(?<=#)(\d+)', expand=False
).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.loc` combined with `apply` which will get all the indexes that are true.

Here is a simple example

```
In [5]: df=  pd.DataFrame({'String_column':['not useful', 'door useful1', '! useful 2', 'not useful']})                                         

In [6]: df                                                                                                                                      
Out[6]: 
  String_column
0    not useful
1  door useful1
2    ! useful 2
3    not useful
```

Now using our function

```
In [7]: df.loc[df['String_column'].apply(lambda x: True if x.startswith('!') or x.startswith('door') else False)]                               
Out[7]: 
  String_column
1  door useful1
2    ! useful 2
```

We used startswith to match all our conditions to get the useful values that starts with '!' or 'door'.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use a non capturing group to list your different options (`#` or `door\s*`):

```
df['num'] = (df['String_column'].str.extract(r'(?:#|door\s*)(\d+)', expand=False)
             .fillna(0).astype(int)
            )
```

output:

```
             String_column  num
0              #12-123,456   12
1  mom101, door 101, pop10  101
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7evmNq/1)